# mq_open() returning -1 error

Tags: posix, message-queue

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    mqd_t mqd;

    mqd = mq_open("/tmp/posix.msg/", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_NONBLOCK, 0666, NULL);
    printf("mq id: %d \n", mqd);
    mq_close(mqd);

    return 0;
```

}

vinay>gcc -o mq mq.c -lrt
vinay>./mq
mq id: -1

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: check `errno` and/or use `perror` to print the error message

Comment: Hi Diego,                                                                                                          I got the following error                                                                               Error : Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

From [mq_overview](http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview):

> Each message queue is identified by a name of the form /somename;
>   that is, a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX (i.e., 255)
>   characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more
>   characters, **none of which are slashes**.

Also, from [mq_open](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_open):

> EACCES
>
> name contained more than one slash.

So, use a name with only one slash at the beginning.